# Own Middleware for Restricting Users Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i am going to write a model which contains following fields example. `user_id`, `role_id`, `company_id`, `functionality_id`, `has_access`. I want to write middleware where user will be `raised NOT ACCESS` where field `has_access` is `false`. Please help how should i do it and i can't use in-built permission due to my dependencies. I have created `middleware.py` and followed official document. This is just my start for writing middleware

```
class ACLMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

i have found some reference to this code but i don't know if it is right way to do because i'm using django 2.1 version

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import Http404

    class RestrictStaffToAdminMiddleware(object):
        """
        A middleware that restricts staff members access to administration panels.
        """
        def process_request(self, request):
            if request.path.startswith(reverse('admin:index')):
                if request.user.is_authenticated():
                    if not request.user.is_staff:
                        raise Http404
                else:
                    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class `RestrictStaffToAdminMiddleware` is use for Django <1.10 which was deprecated the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`. In Django >=1.10, It still supports the old one, You could also use the MiddlewareMixin to make your Middleware compatible.

My class below is for `MIDDLEWARE` Django >1.10, to Restrict the user `is_staff` from Admin Board when the Staff is try to access the Admin Page

- Django >=1.10
- Python 3.6.8

Django document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware

```py
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import Http404

# middleware.py
class RestrictStaffFromAdminMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.path.startswith(reverse('admin:index')):
                if request.user.is_staff and not request.user.is_superuser:
                    raise Http404

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        return HttpResponse("in exception")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put required checks in `__call__` method of your middleware before calling `self.get_response`. It may look like this

```
def __call__(self, request):
    if not request.user.has_access:
        raise PermissionDenied

    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.

    return response
```